# Hailstone sequence using nested while loops

Tags: python, collatz

I'm writing a program that allows the user to input a range of numbers, and then the program will preform a hailstone sequence of each number in the range and will then print the number with the largest cycle length. I cant see why my code isn't working though. We are required to use while loops

```
def main():
    #set starting variables
    start_num = int(input('Enter starting number of the range: '))
    #check if the numbers entered are positive and that the start is less than the end
    while (start_num < 1):
            start_num = int(input('Enter a positive starting number of the range: '))
    end_num = int(input('Enter ending number of the range: '))
    while (end_num < 1):
            end_num = int(input('Enter a positive ending number of the range: '))

    while (start_num > end_num):
            start_num = int(input('Enter starting number of the range: '))
            end_num = int(input('Enter ending number of the range: '))

    cycle_length = 0
    max_length = 0
    num_max = 0
    num = 0

    while (start_num < end_num):

            while (num != 1):

                    if (start_num % 2 == 0):
                            num = start_num / 2
                            cycle_length = cycle_length +1
                    else:
                            num = (start_num * 3) + 1
                            cycle_length = cycle_length +1      

                    if (cycle_length >= max_length):
                            max_length = cycle_length
                            num_max = start_num

                    cycle_length = 0
            start_num = start_num + 1

    print(num_max)
    print(max_length)

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `while` loop, you're always checking `start_num`, which never changes.  At the very beginning of the loop, you need to set `num` to `start_num`.  Then work with `num` throughout the loop body.

Comment: even doing that, the program doesn't ever print anything. It just runs indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to go through each line and tell you what's wrong. You should really make sure that you know what each variable is holding and what it is supposed to hold.

```
def main():
    #set starting variables
    start_num = int(input('Enter starting number of the range: '))
    #check if the numbers entered are positive and that the start is less than the end
    while (start_num < 1):
            start_num = int(input('Enter a positive starting number of the range: '))
    end_num = int(input('Enter ending number of the range: '))
    while (end_num < 1):
            end_num = int(input('Enter a positive ending number of the range: '))

    while (start_num > end_num):
            start_num = int(input('Enter starting number of the range: '))
            end_num = int(input('Enter ending number of the range: '))

    cycle_length = 0
    max_length = 0
    num_max = 0
    num = 0

    while (start_num < end_num):
```

both `start_num` and `end_num` never change, so you have an infinite loop, e.g. while(10 < 100)

```
            while (num != 1):
```

`num` is currently 0, as you have not assigned it to anything after you set it to 0 a few lines ago

```
                    if (start_num % 2 == 0):
                            num = start_num / 2
```

`num` is now `start_num/2`, but `start_num` never changes

```
                            cycle_length = cycle_length +1
                    else:
                            num = (start_num * 3) + 1
```

same here

```
                            cycle_length = cycle_length +1      

                    if (cycle_length >= max_length):
                            max_length = cycle_length
                            num_max = start_num
```

you are setting `num_max` to `start_num` but `start_num` never changes

```
                    cycle_length = 0
```

you are resetting `cycle_num` every cycle

```
            start_num = start_num + 1
     print(num_max)
     print(max_length)

main()
```

Comment: Does the
    start_num = start_num + 1
not change the value for each time it loops?

Comment: `start_num` only changes its value for each number you are generating the sequence for